# RedHawk building from source --- locate the code installing uhd3.5.3

Tags: build, redhawksdr, usrp

I am trying to build from source for RedHawk installation and trying to replace uhd3.5.3 with a higher version of uhd for USRP_UHD module. I saw USRP_UHD source code, but found nowhere for uhd3.5.3 source code. I am guessing it might simply use "yum install ..." to download and install uhd host code and suporting libraries. Does anybody know where this code is located in redhawk_src_2.0 package? Or is there an efficient way in linux to search for this among all the files in redhawk_src_2.0 package?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

UHD is the USRP Harware driver softwware from Ettus Research. The UHD is distributed from:

http://files.ettus.com/binaries/uhd_stable/

Version 3.5.3 is here:

http://files.ettus.com/binaries/uhd_stable/uhd_003.005.003-release/

The current release is 3.9.2:

http://files.ettus.com/binaries/uhd_stable/uhd_003.009.002-release/

Hopefully this helps. I wasn't 100% sure what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2):

First, clone the uhd library:

```
git clone git://github.com/EttusResearch/uhd.git
```

Then checkout the 3.9.2 tag:

```
git checkout release_003_009_002
```

Using the instructions from Ettus (http://files.ettus.com/manual/page_build_guide.html), install the dependencies listed under the Fedora section:

```
sudo yum -y install boost-devel libusb1-devel python-mako doxygen python-docutils cmake make gcc gcc-c++
```

Next, generate the Makefiles with CMake:

```
cd <uhd-repo-path>/host
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/uhd ../
```

I recommend using an alternate install prefix at first to preserve the 3.5.3 version, just in case, but if you don't want to, just run:

```
cmake ../
```

instead of the longer command with the -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX flag. (Note: I couldn't get cmake to find the installed boost version, so you may have to do some other research on that since it is probably a whole different stackoverflow post in and of itself)

Now build and install the uhd library:

```
make
make test
sudo make install
```

Now that the library is installed, you should edit the USRP_UHD/cpp/configure.ac so that the PKG_CONFIG_PATH points to your install prefix (either the one specified in the flag above, or if you did the default, just leave it, as it should already be pointing to /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig). Also in the configure.ac file, make sure to change the uhd version number to 3.9.2.

Now you should be able to rebuild the USRP_UHD Device:

```
./reconf && ./configure && make install
```

I don't guarantee that the Device will build against the new version of the uhd library, that will depend on what (if anything) has been deprecated an removed from the library between the supported version and the newest one.

Finally, if you get through all of those steps successfully and if you specified a non-standard install prefix, you will have to add this prefix to either the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or an /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ script in order for the Device to correctly execute.

Comment: That's a good point, you don't have to change the uhd version number if you don't want to, but it also won't hurt and will convey to anyone who uses your updated Device which version to use. A failure at configuration time is generally more helpful than a build time error.  As for the boost version numbers, that will depend. Is your RH installation linked against 1.41 or 1.46/1.48? If it's linked against 1.41 you can either try to rebuild it against 1.46/1.48 or attempt to have both 1.41 and 1.46/1.48 installed simultaneously and have a RH Device that ends up linking against both versions.

Comment: I would probably try rebuilding the framework against the newer version of boost and hoping that backwards compatibility allows you to build the framework successfully. This way your Device will link against the framework, which is linking against boost 1.46/1.48, and against uhd, which is also linking against 1.46/1.48. The alternative (two versions of boost) sounds unpredictable.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use the RPMs to rebuild against a specified version of boost because they are binary RPMs as opposed to source RPMs (that may also not be possible, I haven't tried it). If that will be the best route for you from a systems perspective, I would look for another SO post about rebuilding rpms. Otherwise, I'd recommend diving into the source install for RH, which isn't too bad, as per Telly Too's post.

Answer (score 0):

Clarification - you can follow the Redhawk manual appendix B for building Redhawk from source AFTER installing UHD v3.9.3 from source as per pwolframs instructions. The UHD v3.5.3 is not packaged with the Redhawk source code, only the Redhawk RPM, disregard all those RPMs when building UHD and Redhawk from source.